# Dell t610 and Windows Server2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell

I have this new server dell powerEdge t610, I am trying to install Win2008R2 but the installation process is being blocked by a missing driver and the windows setup is asking for this driver without telling me anything about this driver. Its just stop and allow me to brows drives to locate the proposed driver. I guessed that its the RAID driver but its the same.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you booting off of the DELL DVD or the Windows DVD?

Comment: I used the Dell DVD and it wouldn't start install, it shows an error and stop. The windows DVD ends with the above error.

Windows 2008 works fine with the Dell dvd setup, the issue  is with Windows2008R2 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell provide a bootable CD/DVD image you can download and boot from, which will preload all the required drivers, and only then ask for the windows CD. This is the preferred way of installing on OS on Dell (or actually any brand name system).

If you want a link to the bootable image, call Dell support - they love easy cases like this one

Comment: after I used "Dell Build and Update tool 1.2" its not recognizing my media

Comment: And what does the Dell support have to say about that?

Comment: they have no chat support, I called them and after 13 mins on menu, waiting, I talked to some guy with very bad English and after another painful 10min he decided that I called the wrong number and i should call another one.

Comment: its solved now... I changed the media and it worked well

Comment: bad ISO? it's always a good idea to verify the checksum of the downloaded images :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Dell Systems Management DVD to install? This will automatically add the required drivers for your server when installing the OS.

Comment: actually yes, I am using the "Dell Build and Update tool 1.2" and I face the issue when the WindowsSetup starts, I even downloaded the n version 1.3 and I am facing another issue now which: its asking for "Windows Installtion pack" and i put my media and it still asking again and agian

Comment: Please boot off of the DELL DVD and do the installation from there.

Answer (score 0):

There an utility from Dell allowing you to prepare a USB key for loading your RAID adaptater driver during windows setup (F6). Here's a link to donwload the [Dell USB Key F6 Driver Utility](http://dell.mydriversdownload.com/ViewDownloadUrl.asp?ID=112870&brNum=3&show=0) and [here](http://hi.baidu.com/actouy/blog/item/18b197630e3d88dae7113ae0.html) is an article covering the procedure for building the USB key.

Answer (score 0):

The T610 also supports systems builds from the embedded Lifecycle Controller and that should support W2K8 with all drivers included. This runs from onboard flash, just press F10 at boot and select the W2K8 build.